# Appcelerator with expansion files

Tags: appcelerator, expansion-files

Has anyone successfully used expansion files with appcelerator?  I have found the module that is supposed to let us work with them, however I am running into the problem of the .obb file being downloaded directly from the play store and then being downloaded again with the module. Aside from that I can't seem to get access to any of the files contained within the .obb using the module.

I have heard all of the woes of having a big app, so please don't just tell me to make a smaller app, my client has a large "library" that they want installed directly on the app. It consists of html files that call javascript files and images through relative paths.

Are expansion files even the way to go with this?  Should I simply zip up my files and download them after, unpack them, and access them using the file system?  I am just looking for a way to get these large files onto the device and access them as if they were in the resources directory of the app.

Any help would be appreciated.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that needs over 300 PNG images and text files (to populate a database with) and could not get the app small enough to put up on the Play Store. What I ended up doing was create a barebones app (enough to get the user started) then I download the files on start up. I didn't mess with zipping everything (the data is constantly being updated), but if the information you have is pretty static, you could zip it. Once the download successfully finishes and installs the data, it sets an app property (Ti.App.Properties.setInt) 0 is never ran, 1 is partial download and 2 is download is installed (you can do this however you want, but that's what I did).